# Imports with Jotai and create react app failing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, jotai

I'm attempting to use the jotai-react-query library, and so I want to leverage

```
import {useHydrateAtoms} from "jotai/react/utils/useHydrateAtoms";
```

However when I'm building a test with jest, it cannot find the import. To verify, I created a blank app with:

```
npx create-react-app jest-example --template typescript
```

and added jotai

```
npm add jotai
```

and then added the import in App.tsx

```
import {useHydrateAtoms} from "jotai/react/utils/useHydrateAtoms";
```

plus a line to use it:

```
const y = useHydrateAtoms([])
```

and same as my project, the import fails:

```
Cannot find module 'jotai/react/utils/useHydrateAtoms' from 'src/App.test.tsx'
```

I've tried poking at some jest options in package.json, but I haven't found a combination that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You're not importing it correctly. Although the type definition for `useHydrateAtoms` comes from the `jotai/react/utils/useHydrateAtoms.d.ts` file, there's no file such as `jotai/react/utils/useHydrateAtoms.js` in the package.

[image: package tree]

Instead, `useHydrateAtoms` is defined in the `jotai/react/utils.js` file. The type definition for the `utils.js` file comes from the `utils.d.ts` file, which imports type definitions from `jotai/react/utils/*.d.ts`.

So, the import that you should be using is -

```ts
import { useHydrateAtoms } from "jotai/react/utils";
```

Comment: No. That is not the problem. Whilst the path may not be correct, the same error persists with the "correct" path.

Comment: @PlexQ Could you create and add a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will solve your issue but it sounds like (if you haven't already) the path to your node modules will need to be set up for jest.

```
"jest": {
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
}
```

Comment: This is setup by default as part of create react app, which does not allow you to change it in the package.json config resulting in a error about Creat React App not supporting this override.